# Force label to display it's text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview

I want to include a voting function similar to the reddit app. I think a `UIStackView` would be perfect for this. Now I'm struggling to make the label between the vote-up and vote-down button display it's text.

[image: Fail]

I've tried to change the contentCompression to `.fittingSizeLevel` and to `.defaultHigh` but this seems to change nothing. On the image you can see, there would be plenty of space to fit the whole text, but it doesn't. What aspect am I missing?

```
class VotingStackView: UIStackView {

    let arrowUpButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.tintColor = GSSettings.UI.Colors.tintColor
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 0, bottom: 16, right: 0)
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        return button
    }()

    let arrowDownButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.tintColor = GSSettings.UI.Colors.tintColor
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 0, bottom: 16, right: 0)
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        return button
    }()

    let percentageLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "100%"
        label.textColor = GSSettings.UI.Colors.regularTextColor
        label.font = GSSettings.UI.Fonts.helveticaLight?.withSize(20)
        label.clipsToBounds = false
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.fittingSizeLevel, for: .horizontal)
        return label
    }()

    var views: [UIView] = [UIView]()

    //MARK: - Init & View Loading
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        views = [arrowUpButton, percentageLabel ,arrowDownButton]
        setupStackView()
        setupImages()
        setupSubviews()
    }

    //MARK: - Setup
    func setupStackView() {
        self.axis           = .horizontal
        self.spacing        = 0
        self.alignment      = .center
        self.distribution   = .fillEqually
    }

    func setupImages() {
        let upImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_up")
        let downImage = UIImage(named: "arrow_down")

        arrowUpButton.setImage(upImage, for: .normal)
        arrowDownButton.setImage(downImage, for: .normal)
    }

    func setupSubviews() {
        for view in views {
            addArrangedSubview(view)
        }
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The votingStackView is part of another StackView:

```
class BottomStackView: UIStackView {

    let votingStackView: VotingStackView = {
        let stackview = VotingStackView()
        return stackview
    }()

    let addFriendButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.tintColor = GSSettings.UI.Colors.tintColor
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        return button
    }()

    let redView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    var views: [UIView] = [UIView]()

    //MARK: - Init & View Loading
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        views = [votingStackView, addFriendButton, redView]
        setupStackView()
        setupSubviews()
    }

    //MARK: - Setup
    func setupStackView() {
        self.axis           = .horizontal
        self.spacing        = 0
        self.alignment      = .leading
        self.distribution   = .fillEqually
    }

    func setupSubviews() {
        for view in views {
            addArrangedSubview(view)
        }
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using constraints to control the width of the stack view? If so, show how you've set up your constraints. If not, show how you're setting the frame.

Comment: okay I did that now.

Comment: OK, but that's still not showing your constraints / frames. In the image you posted, the width of your stack view - based on your arrow images and the label - is no where near the width of the picture. So... are you setting some constraints that are preventing the stack view from filling the width?

Comment: No I've set the leading anchor equal to the leading anchor of the superview, which fills the entire screen. Same with trailing,

Comment: Hmmm... well, that doesn't match the image you posted. The stack view containing the two arrow buttons and the label **definitely** is not stretching the width of the available area. So, *something* is restricting it.

Comment: I got tired of working with UIStackView and built it with a simple UIView instead. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.fittingSizeLevel, for: .horizontal)
```

to

```
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutpriority/1622248-fittingsizelevel) it seems that `fittingSizeLevel` does not take into account parent constraints, so using `defaultHigh` seems like the safer option.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I already tried this and the result is the same.

Comment: I tested your code and I could reproduce your error, and after changing it to `defaultHigh` the problem was corrected. The only other variable I can think of is, how are you adding the stack view to the parent view?

Comment: Added more detail in my question.

Comment: I tested with your update and still cannot reproduce the problem. Can you include the minimum amount of code to make your issue completely reproducible? (i.e. show the code that adds this to the view controller's view). You can see this post for details about what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry, I've deleted my old code. But I promise you I just added a leading and trailing constraint to the superview.